# Difference between deriving typeclass and creating an instance

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have this data type:

```
data TrafficLight = Red | Yellow | Green deriving (Eq)
```

How is it different from creating an instance of `Eq` like so:

```
data TrafficLight = Red | Yellow | Green

instance Eq TrafficLight where
    Red == Red = True  
    Green == Green = True  
    Yellow == Yellow = True  
    _ == _ = False
```

What am I missing here?

**NOTE**

This question is different from the [assumed duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864647) because I am looking for the contrast between the `deriving` and `instance` keyword. The assumed dupe does not mention the `instance` keyword.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864647/how-does-deriving-work-in-haskell

Comment: @Ben That should be an answer.

Comment: @BalinKingOfMoria I've promoted it to one

Comment: @Ben Perfect. Have an upvote for the great answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You aren't missing anything; `deriving` is just having the compiler write out the "obvious" instance for you. It doesn't do anything you couldn't do if you wrote out the instance yourself.

The benefits are (1) you don't have to write out the instance and (2) it communicates to anyone reading the source that the instance **is** the obvious one (rather than having to read the instance definition to determine whether it's non-standard or not).

Comment: There's one exception: `Typeable`. Its instances may *only* be derived.