# Haskell Data Declarations

Tags: haskell

Codes below are from *Programming in Haskell* by Hutton (p.101).

```
data Shape = Circle Float | Rect Float Float

square :: Float -> Shape
square n = Rect n n

area : Shape -> Float
area(Rect x y) = x * y
```

In ghci, if I type area(Rect 3 5), I get 15.
But if I type square 5(thinking that I would get Rect 5 5 as a result), I get an error message:
"No instance for (Show Shape) arising from a use of ‘print’
In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it".

Why is that?

Answer (score 3):

Behind the scenes, GHCi is trying to call `print (square 5)`. Unfortunately this requires `Shape` to implement something called the `Show` typeclass. You can make the error go away by adding `deriving Show` to the end of the `data Shape = Circle Float | Rect Float Float deriving Show`.

There's a [great section on the `Show` typeclass in *Learn You a Haskell*](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses) and [a great answer on deriving in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864647/how-does-deriving-work-in-haskell).