# Implement short-hand instance for Haskell

Tags: class, haskell, polymorphism, instance

When there are many data types which have almost same structure, how can I implement without almost-duplicated codes?

Here is uncompilable code sample to explain the goal.

```haskell
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}

class Category a where
  method :: a -> String

class ForB b where
  ...
class ForC c where
  ...

data A = A {someA :: String, ...}

data B1 = B1 {some :: Int, ...}
data B2 = B2 {some :: Int, ...}
...

data C1 = C1 {some :: Int, ...}
data C2 = C2 {some :: Int, ...}
...

instance Category A where
  method (A x) = x

-- Cannot be compiled, but I want to write like this.
instance Category a where
  method = show . some

instance ForB B1 where
  ....

instance ForC C1 where
  ....

main = do
  let a = A "1"
      b = B1 2
      c = C1 3
  print . method $ a
  print . method $ b
  print . method $ c
```

I understand that `instance` does not take type variable `a` like `instance Something a` but takes only real data type; Is there no polymorphic instance?
I've tried to solve this by introducing new classes like [this](http://lpaste.net/339868), but could not figure it out.
I concerned phantom types or type families, but I could not find any solution.

I do not want to implement almost same code for each data types.
Please refer better explanation and sample to the goal on the background.

**Is there any way to short-hand to implement polymorphic(?) instances** without reducing data type or Template Haskell (lens,record,extensive package).

## Background

I'm preparing series of sample code for transition from OOP to a functional approach.

[Here](http://lpaste.net/339858) is the simplified base code of the explanation.
And [here](http://lpaste.net/339860) is little improvement with `DuplicateRecordFields`.
You can see there are massive instance implements.
(Please do not ask me why do not combine `LifeInfo`, `AnimalInfo` and `Human` in a data type. This is one of the series to solve bunch of problems)
However, to implement `Human`, `Elf`, `Pine` and `Rose`, I write almost same instances for each. And there are some exceptions for `LifeInfo`, `AnimalInfo`, and `PlantInfo`.

## Some points

- Do not combine entry data types(`A`, `B`, and `C`) to a data type by using data constructor like `data ABC = A {..} | B {..} | C {..}`.
  But when you can introduce a method for distinguishing each of them by type-checking or implement class-method like things, it will be good.
  Please notice that there are classes `ForB` and `ForC`.
- I'm avoiding Template Haskell and libraries using TH to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you tried [`deriving`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3864801/736957)? See also [GHC.Generics wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC.Generics).

Comment: I just forget about it. Thanks. I'll try it.

Comment: A [default signature](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#default-method-signatures) on the functions inside `ForA` and `ForB` would allow you to simply write `instance ForA X` for an appropriately defined `X`.