# Removing repetitions from multiple instance declarations

Tags: haskell

I've currently got code following this pattern:

```
f1' x1 x2 .. xm1 = ...
f2' x1 x2 .. xm2 = ...
.
.
,
fn' x1 x2 .. xmn = ...

instance C D1 where
  f1 = f1'
  f2 = f2'
  .
  .
  .
  fn = fn'

instance C D2 where
  f1 = f1'
  f2 = f2'
  .
  .
  .
  fn = fn'

.
.
.

instance C DN where
  f1 = f1'
  f2 = f2'
  .
  .
  .
  fn = fn'
```

Basically, I've got a class that I want to implement for a number of datatypes, but all these implementations are the same. But there's a lot of repeated code with the instance implementations, for `m` functions and `n` instances, I have to write roughly `O(m*n)` lines of code, I'd prefer it to be more like `O(m+n)`.

Is there a good way to remove the repetition here? I imagine Template Haskell would do the trick, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if something to handle this already exists.

Comment: If they are all the same, can't you just provide default implementations?

Comment: I can't do that sadly, I don't control the class (`C` is actually `Enum` in my case).

Comment: Instead of the abstract example, could you add two of your types as well as your functions?

Comment: I don't know if there's something simpler than Template Haskell for this.

Comment: Sometimes in cases like this I put all the definitions of each instance on single line, eases the visual pain and shows the repetition more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a default implementation for your class. Take the `Functor` example:

```
class  Functor f  where
    fmap        :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

     -- | Replace all locations in the input with the same value.
     -- The default definition is @'fmap' . 'const'@, but this may be
     -- overridden with a more efficient version.
    (<$)        :: a -> f b -> f a
    (<$)        =  fmap . const
```

You can also opt for the `deriving` option which you can found more information in this question: [How does deriving work in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864647/how-does-deriving-work-in-haskell) There is some information on how to control `deriving`.

Comment: C is not my class only the instances are mine

Comment: is deriving an option ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could first create another empty type class:

```
class SomeD
```

Then make the types `D1` ... `DN` instances of `SomeD` using a single line for each type:

```
instance SomeD D1
-- ...
instance SomeD DN
```

Then make any instance of the `SomeD` typeclass an instance of `C` like so:

```
instance (SomeD t) => C t where
    f1 = f1'
    -- ...
    fn = fn'
```

(I'm not sure if this works or if it needs some language extensions but unfortunately I can't test it right now.)

Comment: This does not work and there's not really an extension which allows it to.  The only case where this works is if there are no other implementations of `C`.  Yes you can get it to compile but when you try to use it everything gets messy.