# What does deriving do/mean in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, deriving

The definition of deriving on stack overflow is:

> "In Haskell, a derived instance is an instance declaration that is
>   generated automatically in conjunction with a data or newtype
>   declaration. The body of a derived instance declaration is derived
>   syntactically from the definition of the associated type."

I don't really understand any of it to be honest.

The code below is taken from: [Link](http://www.newthinktank.com/2015/08/learn-haskell-one-video/)

```
data BaseballPlayer = Pitcher 
                        | Catcher
                        | Infielder
                        | Outfielder
                        deriving Show

barryBonds :: BaseballPlayer -> Bool
barryBonds Outfielder = True

barryInOf = print(barryBonds Outfielder)
```

**My question is, what does the deriving-statement do in this specific case, 
and also what does the deriving-statement do in general?.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does deriving work in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864647/how-does-deriving-work-in-haskell)

Comment: No, it is not a duplicate.

Comment: It is hard to answer your question because you didn't set up the context. Your only statement is "I don't know (this or that)". Things you don't know need to be explained in terms of things you do know, and no one has a slightest idea what these are. Should we start from types? Functions?
 Classes and instances? No clue. As it is, the question is overly broad.

Comment: You can actually just see exactly what it does by passing the flag `-ddump-deriv` to GHC. This will print the code generated by all `deriving` clauses. That is all it does - generates some boilerplate for you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**In short:**

`deriving` automatically implements functions for a few of Haskell's typeclasses such as `Show` and `Eq`. This cannot be done with arbitrary typeclasses, but the ones for which `deriving` does work for are simple enough for automatic implementation.

The `Show` typeclass defines functions for how to represent data types as a `String`.

**More extensively:**

Are you familiar with typeclasses?

https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/classes.html

Typeclasses are similar to interfaces in Java: they define a few functions that any data type who wants to use those functions can implement.

For instance, say we have a class like such:

```
class Comparable a where
    lessThan :: a -> a -> Bool
    equalsTo :: a -> a -> Bool
```

Beware of the word `class`. It means typeclass in the Haskell setting, not a typical "class" you would hear about in object oriented languages. The `a` here is a filler type, similar to how you would expect templates would work in C++ and generics to behave in Java.

Let's say we define a data type as follows:

```
data Color = Red | Green | Blue
```

To make `Comparable` work with `Color`, we implement an `instance` of `Comparable`:

```
instance Comparable Color where
    lessThan Red   Green = True
    lessThan Red   Blue  = True
    lessThan Green Blue  = True
    lessThan _     _     = False

    equalsTo Red   Red   = True
    equalsTo Green Green = True
    equalsTo Blue  Blue  = True
    equalsTo _     _     = False
```

Roughly speaking, this now allows you to "compare" `Red`, `Green`, and `Blue` with each other. But was there any way that GHC could have automagically guessed that this is was the exact "order" you wanted?

Taking a step back, the typeclass `Show` has a similar structure:

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Show.html#Show

```
class  Show a  where
    showsPrec :: Int -> a -> ShowS
    show      :: a   -> String
    showList  :: [a] -> ShowS

    showsPrec _ x s = show x ++ s
    show x          = shows x ""
    showList ls   s = showList__ shows ls s
```

Something to notice is that functions within a typeclass may be defined in terms of each other. Indeed, we could have also easily done:

```
class Comparable a where
    lessThan :: a -> a -> Bool
    equalsTo :: a -> a -> Bool

    greaterThan :: a -> a -> Bool
    greaterThan lhs rhs = not (lessThan lhs rhs && equalsTo lhs rhs)
```

However, the key point is this: for arbitrary user-defined typeclasses, GHC has no idea how their functions should be implemented when you try to associate the typeclass with a data type such as `Color` or `BaseballPlayer`. For **some** typeclasses such as `Show`, `Eq`, `Ord`, etc, where the functionality is simple enough, GHC can generate default implementations that you can of course overwrite yourself.

Indeed, let's experiment by trying to compile the following:

```
data Color = Red | Green | Blue deriving (Comparable)
```

The result I get is this:

```
test.hs:9:43:
    Can't make a derived instance of ‘Comparable Color’:
      ‘Comparable’ is not a derivable class
      Try enabling DeriveAnyClass
    In the data declaration for ‘Color’
```

Of course, some GHC extensions can be used to extend the power of `deriving`, but that's for another day :)

Answer (score 6):

In this specific case, it generates a `Show` instance for your type, as follows:

```
instance Show BaseballPlayer where
    show Pitcher    = "Pitcher"
    show Catcher    = "Catcher"
    show Infielder  = "Infielder"
    show Outfielder = "Outfielder"
```

In this way, values of type `BaseballPlayer` can be converted to string, e.g. by `print`.

The string is chosen so that it is a valid Haskell expression that can reconstruct, once evaluated, the original value.

The general case is a bit more complex, but follows the same idea: converting a value into a Haskell expression-string. For instance

```
data T = T Int (Maybe Bool) deriving Show
```

will make the instance so that

```
show (T 1 Nothing) = "T 1 Nothing"
show (T 2 (Just 3)) = "T 2 (Just 3)"
```

Note how the parentheses are also generated in the last case. This is done using the `showsPrec` class member, but it's not that important.

Answer (score 3):

Deriving means that your data type is automatically able to "derive" instances for certain type classes. In this case `BaseballPlayer` derives `Show` which means we can use any function that requires an instance of `Show` to work with `BaseballPlayer`.

Automatic deriving makes it easier for you to avoid boilerplate. The most common type classes for automatic deriving are `Show` and `Eq`, because the compiler can make very sensible values for these typeclasses.