# Deriving a class with a single constant

Tags: haskell

I would like to derive a class with a constant and some trivial operations:

```
class  Zeros z where
    zero :: z
    isZero  :: Eq z =>  z -> Bool
    isZero z = zero == z
```

and in another module:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric, DeriveAnyClass
    , GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
module Lib.DerivingExampleDerive
    where
import Data.Text
import Lib.DerivingExample
import GHC.Generics

newtype Basis1 = Basis1 Text deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord, Generic, Zeros)
```

GHC 8.2.2 produces the error:

```
/home/frank/Workspace8/testSome/Lib/DerivingExampleDerive.hs:26:70: warning:
    • Both DeriveAnyClass and GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving are enabled
      Defaulting to the DeriveAnyClass strategy for instantiating Zeros
    • In the newtype declaration for ‘Basis1’
   |         
26 | newtype Basis1 = Basis1 Text deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord, Generic, Zeros)
   |                                                                      ^^^^^

/home/frank/Workspace8/testSome/Lib/DerivingExampleDerive.hs:26:70: warning: [-Wmissing-methods]
    • No explicit implementation for
        ‘zero’
    • In the instance declaration for ‘Zeros Basis1’
   |         
26 | newtype Basis1 = Basis1 Text deriving (Show, Read, Eq, Ord, Generic, Zeros)
   |                                                                      ^^^^^
```

I understand the first message (considering [Ryan Scott's blog post on deriving strategies](https://ryanglscott.github.io/2017/04/12/improvements-to-deriving-in-ghc-82/) but not the second.

Should I conclude that the deriving mechanism in Haskell cannot derive constants?  I have given

```
instance Zeros Text where zero = (""::Text)
```

and the derivation for

```
instance Zeros Basis1 where zero = Basis1 zero
```

should be resulting from the strategy of `DeriveAnyClass` but is not.

Comment: How should Haskell know what the `zero` element should be? But indeed, only for some specific cases, Haskell can perform automatic derivations.

Comment: Could you point me to the list of the `specific cases` ? what is different in the expected derived instance for Basis1 compared to deriving, e.g., show? The newtype constructor is added.. - Would it be difficutl to implement in GHC to derive for constans?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3864746/67579

Comment: and you do not really provide a way to derive what `zero` is, a conservative compiler can thus not simply make a lucky guess.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I must miss something: An instance for Text is given and I assume that the derivation for the newtype `Basis1 Text` should use it automatically - the same it would for `show`. In https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.4.2/docs/html/users_guide/generic-programming.html mechanism for deriving constants are mentioned; should I use the mechanism described there?

Answer (score 3):

`GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` will write the instance you propose, but `DeriveAnyClass` will write this instance:

```
instance Zeros Text => Zeros Basis1
```

N.B. there are no method definitions! For that to work, you need to give a default implementation for every method; usually this is done with [generics](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html) or a similar generic programming toolkit.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer to GHC.Generics, which I read but do not see how to apply it here. I have (naively) coded:                           class   Zeros z where
    zero :: z
    default zero :: (Generic z, Gzero (Rep z)) => z 
    zero = gzero (from z) 

class Gzero f  where 
    gzero :: f a -> a 
instance Gzero U1 where
    gzero U1 = a
but  got errors on both lines with gzero.  I tried to derive Monoid from Data.Monoid, but cannot derive it for a data type (but for newtypes). Can automatic derivatin of Zeros not be done or can my code be improved? if not, why?

Comment: @user855443 Please open a fresh question with the details of your attempt (including an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) and the exact error message it produces.

Comment: Thank you for the advice: the new question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49276305/how-to-write-an-instance-for-generic-to-derive-a-function-like-zeroa-i-e-a-c

Answer (score 2):

You pointed to Ryan's blog post that explains a fix. Why don't you use it? Add `DerivingStrategies` and then use `deriving newtype Zeros`.

Comment: I use this solution, but it is limited to types defined as newtype and does not work for `data X = X .. `. where I think I can only use the deriving strategy `anyclass` which does not produce an instance for the function `zero`.

Comment: @user855443, yes, but your question asked about `newtype`. Was that unintentional?

Comment: I learned only from the advice i received that newtype deriving is only applicable to newtype definitions and that for data definitions i need anyclass. therefore Ryan's very useful blog post solved most of my problem and left the case where anyclass is required open. The question was posed with incomplete understanding...