# How to write an instance for Generic to derive a function like zero::a (i.e. a constant)?

Tags: haskell

I would like to derive with the `anyclass` strategy for the `class Zeros`. For this i need a default implementation and the corresponding instances for Generics:

```
import GHC.Generics

class   Zeros z where
    zero :: z
    default zero :: (Generic z, Gzero (Rep z)) => z
    zero = gzero (from z)

class Gzero f  where
    gzero :: f a -> a
instance Gzero (Rec0 Int) where
    gzero (Rec0 i a) = a


data B1 = B1 Int
     deriving stock (Show, Read, Eq, Ord, Generic)
deriving instance Zeros B1


instance Zeros Int where zero = 0
```

I get the error message (with stack LTS 10.8 - GHC 8.2.2):

```
Not in scope: data constructor ‘Rec0’
    Perhaps you meant ‘Rec1’ (imported from GHC.Generics)
   |
37 |     gzero (Rec0 i a) = a
   |            ^^^^
```

I have read the documentation for GHC.Generics, but cannot make the leap from the tree example to my case with a constant function. 
Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The sole constructor for the type `Rec0` is `K1`, and it takes only one argument, not two...

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I have now: class   Zeros z where
    zero :: z
    default zero :: (Generic z, Gzero (Rep z)) => z
    zero = gzero (from z)

class Gzero f  where
    gzero :: f a -> a
instance Gzero (Rec0 Int) where
    gzero (K1 i) = i
but something is still wrong:
    Variable not in scope: z
30 |     zero = gzero (from z)  and 
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable...
          gzero :: forall a. Rec0 Int a -> a
      
  
      In an equation for ‘gzero’: gzero (K1 i) = i
...
35 |     gzero (K1 i) = i

Comment: You seem to be consistently confusing types and terms. `Rec0 i a` might be a type, but is not a term, which explains the error in the question. Similarly, in `zero :: z; zero = gzero (from z)`, `z` is a type and not a term, which explains the error in your followup comment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know that I am confused and I hope for clarification. I have not found the word `term` neither in GHC.Generics nor in the wiki page, therefore I do not understand what is wrong. Could you point me to an example for a similar case (e.g. monoid) or show me what I have to fix (i.e. paste a fixed piece of code). I know that this is aksing much, but if Generics should become useful for the non-specialist, more examples are required..

Comment: The things I said above have nothing to do with generics (and can't, because I don't know anything about generics). The distinction between type-level stuff and term-/value-level stuff is a fundamental one in Haskell, so if you haven't got a firm grip on that, I'd suggest starting with a Haskell tutorial and covering the basics of standard programming before you try to get into advanced generic programming.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that Generics are Type Level Programming. I did not make this connection, despite having experimented with it since Kiselyovs et al. original paper in 2004. I do not think that this is part of  "standard Haskell programming". - But: if you do not know anything about generics, why do you answers questions on it? I still think it would be useful to be able to derive Monoid. If somebody can help?

Comment: Generics are not type-level programming, and I don't believe I either said or implied that. And as far as I know, I have not written any answers to questions on generics, including this one.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you want your function to do. What is `zeros` supposed to yield if you derive it for a `String`, or a `[Int]`, or a `Bool`, or an `Either Int Bool`?

Comment: For the base types (String, Int, [], Bool etc.) instances must be given in the code (as in the example code above for Int), but I would expect that a type like `data B1 = B1 Int` gets a derived  instance with `zero = B1 0`. Zero is like the identity of the Monoid class (mempty)

Comment: If you want generic instances of your classes but don't want to learn the details of GHC.Generics, you can use my one-liner package. Then the implementation is nothing more than `zero = nullaryOp @Zeros zero`. Here's a complete example: https://gist.github.com/sjoerdvisscher/050ceb08b6fcb68cda64d5b5eac7e235

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, since you said in the comments that what you're aiming for semantically is something like deriving `Monoid`, let's do that.

#### General observations

A class like `Monoid` is easy to derive for "sum types", i.e., types having more than one constructor, but it is possible to derive it for pure "product types", i.e., types having a single constructor and just one or more arguments. Let's focus just on `zero`, which corresponds to `mempty`, and is the subject of your question:

- if the single constructor has no arguments, we simply use that constructor,
- if the single constructor has one argument (as your `B1` example), then we require that argument to have a `Zero` instance already and use the `zero` of that type,
- if the single constructor has more than one argument, we do the same for all these arguments: we require all of them to have a `Zero` instance and then use `zero` for all of these.

So really, we can phrase this as one simple rule: for all arguments of the single constructor, just apply `zero`.

We have the choice of several approaches to generic programming to implement this rule. You've been asking about `GHC.Generics`, and I will explain how to do it in that approach, but let me nevertheless first explain how to do it with the [generics-sop](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop) package, because I think one can more directly transcribe the rule identified above into code in this approach.

#### Solution using generics-sop

With generics-sop, your code looks as follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
module Zero where

import qualified GHC.Generics as GHC
import Generics.SOP

class Zero a where
  zero :: a
  default zero :: (IsProductType a xs, All Zero xs) => a
  zero = to (SOP (Z (hcpure (Proxy @Zero) (I zero))))

instance Zero Int where
  zero = 0
```

Most of the code is enabling language extensions and the module header. Let's look at the rest:

We are declaring the `Zero` class with the `zero` method as you did. Then we give a default signature for the `zero` method explaining under which conditions we can derive it. The type signature says that the type has to be a product type (i.e., have a single constructor). The `xs` is then bound to a list of types corresponding to the types of all the constructor arguments. The `All Zero xs` constraint says that all these argument types also have to be an instance of the `Zero` class.

The code is then a one-liner, although admittedly a lot is going on in that line. The `to` call in transforms the produces generic representation into a value of the actually desired type in the end. The `SOP . Z` combination says we want to produce a value of the first (and only) constructor of the datatype. The `hcpure (Proxy @Zero) (I zero)` call produces as many copies of calls to `zero` as there are arguments of the constructor.

In order to try it, we can define datatypes and derive instances of `Zero` for them now:

```
data B1 = B1 Int
  deriving (GHC.Generic, Generic, Show)

deriving instance Zero B1

data B2 = B2 Int B1 Int
  deriving (GHC.Generic, Generic, Show)

deriving instance Zero B2
```

Because generics-sop is built on top of GHC generics, we have to define two `Generic` classes. The `GHC.Generic` class built into GHC, and the `Generic` class provided by generics-sop. The `Show` class is just for convience and testing.

It's a bit unfortunate that even with the `DeriveAnyClass` extension, we cannot simply add `Zero` to the list of derived instances here, because GHC has difficulties inferring that the instance context should actually be empty. Perhaps a future version of GHC will be clever enough to recognise this. But in a standalone deriving declaration, we can explicitly provide the (empty) instance context and it is fine. In GHCi, we can see that this works:

```
GHCi> zero :: B1
B1 0
GHCi> zero :: B2
B2 0 (B1 0) 0
```

#### Solution using GHC generics

Let's look how we can do the same thing directly with GHC generics. Here, the code looks as follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
module Zero where

import GHC.Generics

class Zero a where
  zero :: a
  default zero :: (Generic a, GZero (Rep a)) => a
  zero = to gzero

instance Zero Int where
  zero = 0

class GZero a where
  gzero :: a x

instance GZero U1 where
  gzero = U1

instance Zero a => GZero (K1 i a) where
  gzero = K1 zero

instance (GZero a, GZero b) => GZero (a :*: b) where
  gzero = gzero :*: gzero

instance GZero a => GZero (M1 i c a) where
  gzero = M1 gzero
```

The start is mostly what you also had in your question. The default signature for `zero` says that if `a` has a `Generic` instance and the type's generic representation `Rep a` is an instance of `GZero`, we can obtain a definition of `zero` by first calling `gzero`, and then using `to` to transform the generic representation into the actual type.

We now have to give instances for the `GZero` class. We provide instances for `U1`, `K1`, `(:*:)` and `M1`, telling GHC how to deal with unit types (i.e., constructors without arguments), constants, pairs (binary products) and metadata, respectively. By not providing an instance for `(:+:)`, we implicitly exclude sum types (which was a bit more explicit via the `IsProductType` constraint in generics-sop).

The instance for `U1` says that for a unit type we simply return the unique value.

The instance for constants (these are the arguments of a constructor) says that for these, we need them to also be an instance of the `Zero` class and use a recursive call to `zero`.

The instance for pairs says that in this case we produce a pair of `gzero` calls. This instance is applied repeatedly if a constructor has more than two arguments.

The instance for metadata says that we want to ignore all metadata such as constructor names and record field selectors. We did not have to do anything about metadata in generics-sop, because GHC generics mixes metadata into the representation of every value, whereas in generics-sop it is separate.

From here one, it's basically the same:

```
data B1 = B1 Int
  deriving (Generic, Show, Zero)

data B2 = B2 Int B1 Int
  deriving (Generic, Show, Zero)
```

This is a bit simpler, as we only have to derive a single `Generic` class, and in this scenario, GHC is clever enough to figure out the instance context for `Zero`, so we can just add it to the list of derived instances. The interaction with GHCi is exactly the same, so I won't repeat it here.

#### So what about mappend?

Now that we have `zero` which corresponds to `mzero`, perhaps you want to extend the class to cover `mappend` next. This is also possible, and of course, you're welcome to try it as an exercise.

If you want to see solutions:

For generics-sop, you can look at my [ZuriHac talk from 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sQxH349HOik) which explains generics-sop in a bit more detail and uses how to derive `Monoid` instances as the initial example.

For GHC generics, you can look at the [generic-deriving](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-deriving) package which contains many example generic programs, including monoids. The source code
of the [`Generics.Deriving.Monoid` module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-deriving-1.12.1/docs/src/Generics-Deriving-Monoid.html#GMonoid') contains the class instances for `GMonoid'` which are corresponding to `GZero` above and also contain code for `mappend`.

Comment: Using yet another library called [one-liner](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/one-liner), which is a bit similar to generics-sop but slightly less heavy on type-level stuff, you can write `zero` in a yet more straight-forward way. See https://gist.github.com/sjoerdvisscher/050ceb08b6fcb68cda64d5b5eac7e235

Comment: Regarding the necessity to use standalone deriving when deriving the `Zero` class via generics-sop: this seems to be a GHC bug, see https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/14932

Comment: thank you a lot - i will try it out in the next days!

Comment: The extensive answer by kosmikus was extremely useful to understand the issue (especially that I need `TypeOperators` and multiple instances of GZero). I tried the generic and the one-liner answer - both work as described. I will go for the plain generic one; it is more code when declaring the generic, but simpler when using it. This may change after ghc 8.4 fixed the bug (I am on 8.2.2).