# How to write an instance for Generic to derive a function like singleton:: a -> f a

Tags: haskell

With the advice I have received before ([How to write an instance for Generic to derive a function like zero::a (i.e. a constant)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49276305/how-to-write-an-instance-for-generic-to-derive-a-function-like-zeroa-i-e-a-c)) I succeded with append and similar functions, but failed with a function to convert a single value in a value wrapped with a type (e.g. singleton :: a -> [a]).

I have so far:

```
class Single l   where
    mkOne :: x -> l    
    default mkOne :: (Generic l, Generic x, Single l, Gsingle (Rep l)) => x -> l  
    mkOne x = to ( gmkOne (from x))

class Gsingle l where 
    gmkOne :: x -> l x

instance Gsingle U1 where   -- this is for zero
  gmkOne x = U1

instance  (Gsingle a) => Gsingle (K1 i a) where
    gmkOne (K1 x) = K1 (mkOne x)

instance Single f => Gsingle (M1 i c f) where
  gmkOne (M1 x1) = M1 (gmkOne x1)

instance (Gsingle f, Gsingle h) => Gsingle (f :*: h) where
  gmkOne  (x1 :*: y1) = gmkOne x1:*: gmkOne y1
```

I have the impression from looking at examples that I do not understand the `x` type parameter in `Gsingle`, or rather how to deal with the signature `x -> lx` in the Gsingle.

I tried to use type families:

```
class Single l   where
    type ST l 
    mkOne :: (ST l) -> l    
    default mkOne :: (Generic l, Generic (ST l), Single l, Gsingle (Rep l)) => (ST l) -> l  
    mkOne x = to ( gmkOne (from x))

class Gsingle l where 
    type STG l 
    gmkOne :: (STG l)  -> l x
instance Gsingle U1 where   -- this is for zero
  gmkOne x = U1

instance  (Gsingle a) => Gsingle (K1 i a) where
    gmkOne (K1 x) = K1 (mkOne x)

instance Single f => Gsingle (M1 i c f) where
  gmkOne (M1 x1) = M1 (gmkOne x1)

instance (Gsingle f, Gsingle h) => Gsingle (f :*: h) where
  gmkOne  (x1 :*: y1) = gmkOne x1:*: gmkOne y1
```

but the type erros in the instances `Gsingle (M1 i c f)` and `Gsingle (f :*: h)` remain.

Comment: Can you post the error messages?

Answer (score 2):

This class is usually called "pointed", and can be represented as such:

```
class Pointed f where
  point :: a -> f a
  default point :: (Generic1 f, Pointed (Rep1 f)) => a -> f a
  point = to1 . point
```

You just need instances for each constructor:

```
instance Pointed c => Pointed (M1 i t c) where
  point = M1 . point

instance Monoid c => Pointed (K1 i c) where
  point _ = K1 mempty

instance Pointed U1 where
  point _ = U1

instance Pointed r => Pointed (l :+: r) where
  point = R1 . point

instance (Pointed l, Pointed r) => Pointed (l :*: r) where
  point x = point x :*: point x

instance Pointed Par1 where
  point = Par1

instance Pointed f => Pointed (Rec1 f) where
  point = Rec1 . point

instance (Pointed l, Pointed r) => Pointed (l :.: r) where
  point = Comp1 . point . point
```

Then it'll work fine:

```
data Three a = Three a a a deriving (Show,Generic1)

>>> point True :: Three Bool
Three True True True

instance Pointed []

>>> point True :: [Bool]
[True,True,True,True,True,True...
```

You might notice a similarity to `pure` in the `Applicative` class: there's actually [a proposal](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2018-February/028562.html) on the GHC libraries mailing list to add this precise instance to each constructor above.

Comment: Thank you a lot - it works! I did not know that I have to use Generic1. Why is here no `Gpointed` (or `Pointed'`) class required? I wanted to use the class for `newtype T = T x`, i.e. types of kind * but Pointed works only on types with kind `*->*` - correct? What need to be changed?